# how do i run (command : "ionic start myApp sidemenu") while "github.com" is blocked by DNS

Tags: ionic-framework

After running the command `ionic start myApp sidemenu` getting following error:

> D:\ionic 2>ionic start myApp sidemenu ✔ Creating directory .\myApp -
>   done! [INFO] Fetching app base
>   (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
>   ✖ Downloading - failed! Error: write EPROTO
>   101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:

Any body know whats my wrong?

Comment: I'm asking any alternative way to run "ionic start myApp sidemenu", OR alternative domain other than "github.com" for ionic pakage download.

Comment: You could try to use vpn connection to circumvent the dns block. There are tools like private tunnel.

Comment: is their any reference to watch or read?

Comment: nah sry.. its just a vpn so you download from github over another server with is not blocked by your dns. Should work.